# Integrating Hudson plugin into Redmine

Tags: hudson, redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to add the Hudson plugin to Redmine but I have some errors.

```
Mysql::Error: Table 'redmine_default.hudson_settings' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM `hudson_settings` WHERE (project_id = 3)  LIMIT 1

RAILS_ROOT: /usr/share/redmine
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:324:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:639:in `select'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:81:in `cache_sql'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:1539:in `find_initial'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:617:in `find'
/usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_hudson/app/models/hudson_settings.rb:27:in `load'
/usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_hudson/app/controllers/hudson_controller.rb:110:in `find_settings'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in `run_before_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in `call_filters'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'....
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for answer, run this :

```
$ rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV="production"
```

or

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV="production"
```